# How to mount an remote filesystem with specifying a port number

Tags: linux, nfs, mount

I am trying to mount a director from another server on my server.

For that, I have tested

```
 sudo mount -t nfs 11.11.11.111:/some_directory /mnt/test/
```

But the connections gets a timeout because on the server I am using another port: 1122

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15):

You can specify options using the flag `-o key=value`. In this case:

```
 sudo mount -o port=1122 -t nfs 11.11.11.111:/some_directory /mnt/test/
```

For more information, do `man mount_nfs`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just tryed but there is no answer from the mount command, it stays there since 15min without giving any feedback

Answer (score 3):

If I recall correctly you use the port= option to specify destination port. For example:

```
sudo mount -t nfs -o port=1122 11.11.11.111:/some_directory /mnt/test/
```